# React native vibration not working on android

Tags: android, react-native

I try to implement the Vibration class from react-native.
I added this call to a testing button:

```js
Vibration.vibrate(1000)
```

Besides that I have added this line to both AndroidManifest.java files:

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

(I don't know if I need to add it to both, I did just to be sure)

I tried deleting my android/app/build before re-building but my phone doesn't vibrate.
It's not on silent mode or something like that, the vibration features of other apps are working.